# Next/previous buttons Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the last few days, I've been stuck in finding a next/previous javascript function for searching a string into a textarea. The function should scroll up or down depending on the search mode.
This textarea contains text that is hard to find manually, so what I would like to do, is having a method for searching a specific string into this textarea to facilitate navigation for the user. I found this nice findNext javascript function by Alan Koontz http://jsfiddle.net/bosshmb/7Tg7d/

```
/******************************************
* Find In Page Script -- Submitted/revised by Alan Koontz (alankoontz@REMOVETHISyahoo.com)
* Visit Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/) for full source code
* This notice must stay intact for use
******************************************/

//  revised by Alan Koontz -- May 2003

var TRange = null;
var dupeRange = null;
var TestRange = null;
var win = null;


//  SELECTED BROWSER SNIFFER COMPONENTS DOCUMENTED AT
//  http://www.mozilla.org/docs/web-developer/sniffer/browser_type.html

var nom = navigator.appName.toLowerCase();
var agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_major   = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
var is_minor   = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
var is_ie      = (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1);
var is_ie4up   = (is_ie && (is_major >= 4));
var is_not_moz = (agt.indexOf('netscape')!=-1)
var is_nav     = (nom.indexOf('netscape')!=-1);
var is_nav4    = (is_nav && (is_major == 4));
var is_mac     = (agt.indexOf("mac")!=-1);
var is_gecko   = (agt.indexOf('gecko') != -1);
var is_opera   = (agt.indexOf("opera") != -1);


//  GECKO REVISION

var is_rev=0
if (is_gecko) {
temp = agt.split("rv:")
is_rev = parseFloat(temp[1])
}


//  USE THE FOLLOWING VARIABLE TO CONFIGURE FRAMES TO SEARCH
//  (SELF OR CHILD FRAME)

//  If you want to search another frame, change from "self" to
//  the name of the target frame:
//  e.g., var frametosearch = 'main'

//var frametosearch = 'main';
var frametosearch = self;


function search(whichform, whichframe) {

//  TEST FOR IE5 FOR MAC (NO DOCUMENTATION)

if (is_ie4up && is_mac) return;

//  TEST FOR NAV 6 (NO DOCUMENTATION)

if (is_gecko && (is_rev <1)) return;

//  TEST FOR Opera (NO DOCUMENTATION)

if (is_opera) return;

//  INITIALIZATIONS FOR FIND-IN-PAGE SEARCHES

if(whichform.findthis.value!=null && whichform.findthis.value!='') {

       str = whichform.findthis.value;
       win = whichframe;
       var frameval=false;
       if(win!=self)
{

       frameval=true;  // this will enable Nav7 to search child frame
       win = parent.frames[whichframe];

}


}

else return;  //  i.e., no search string was entered

var strFound;

//  NAVIGATOR 4 SPECIFIC CODE

if(is_nav4 && (is_minor < 5)) {

  strFound=win.find(str); // case insensitive, forward search by default

//  There are 3 arguments available:
//  searchString: type string and it's the item to be searched
//  caseSensitive: boolean -- is search case sensitive?
//  backwards: boolean --should we also search backwards?
//  strFound=win.find(str, false, false) is the explicit
//  version of the above
//  The Mac version of Nav4 has wrapAround, but
//  cannot be specified in JS


        }

//  NAVIGATOR 7 and Mozilla rev 1+ SPECIFIC CODE (WILL NOT WORK WITH NAVIGATOR 6)

if (is_gecko && (is_rev >= 1)) {

    if(frameval!=false) win.focus(); // force search in specified child frame
    strFound=win.find(str, false, false, true, false, frameval, false);

//  The following statement enables reversion of focus 
//  back to the search box after each search event 
//  allowing the user to press the ENTER key instead
//  of clicking the search button to continue search.
//  Note: tends to be buggy in Mozilla as of 1.3.1
//  (see www.mozilla.org) so is excluded from users 
//  of that browser.

    if (is_not_moz)  whichform.findthis.focus();

//  There are 7 arguments available:
//  searchString: type string and it's the item to be searched
//  caseSensitive: boolean -- is search case sensitive?
//  backwards: boolean --should we also search backwards?
//  wrapAround: boolean -- should we wrap the search?
//  wholeWord: boolean: should we search only for whole words
//  searchInFrames: boolean -- should we search in frames?
//  showDialog: boolean -- should we show the Find Dialog?


}

 if (is_ie4up) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE revised 5/21/03

  if (TRange!=null) {

   TestRange=win.document.body.createTextRange();



   if (dupeRange.inRange(TestRange)) {

   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
    if (strFound) {
        //the following line added by Mike and Susan Keenan, 7 June 2003
        win.document.body.scrollTop = win.document.body.scrollTop + TRange.offsetTop;
        TRange.select();
        }


   }

   else {

     TRange=win.document.body.createTextRange();
     TRange.collapse(false);
     strFound=TRange.findText(str);
     if (strFound) {
        //the following line added by Mike and Susan Keenan, 7 June 2003
        win.document.body.scrollTop = TRange.offsetTop;
        TRange.select();
        }



   }
  }

   if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=win.document.body.createTextRange();
   dupeRange = TRange.duplicate();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
    if (strFound) {
        //the following line added by Mike and Susan Keenan, 7 June 2003
        win.document.body.scrollTop = TRange.offsetTop;
        TRange.select();
        }


   }

 }

  if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!") // string not found
}
```

It works fine, but it only searches for the next string occurence. I don't want to invest more time on writing my own function, because I am not that good in javascript... And that it may be was developed previously by one javascripter. Please let me know if there is a function that meets my requirement.

Comment: Ohm...everything is commented..why is so

Comment: I didn't notice, fixed now :)

Comment: Any reason why browser sniffing is needed? It's generally bad practice. You can usually find a function to call and if that function doesn't exist in the browser's javascript interpreters then provide an alternative, such as IE and preventdefault - if(event.preventDefault) {event.preventDefault();} else {event.returnValue = false;}.

Comment: the function is highly sensible to the browser's type. That's why it is sniffing the browser to get the exact browser's name in order to have an all platform working function

Comment: Can't you rewrite the function so it won't be? I guess what you're doing will be so hard to maintain. Imagine future versions or browsers?